# Docker on GCloud Vertex AI: We receive no predictions in our answer

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We try to deploy a Docker container on Google Cloud Vertex AI. However, every time we send a request to the Vertex AI, we only get a response with the model specifications but not the predictions by the model (see picture)

[image]

Herewith also the code of the app.py file we use:

```
class PredictionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def __init__(
    self,
    application: "Application",
    request: tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest,
    **kwargs: Any
  ) -> None:
    super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
  def post(self):
    response_body = None
    try:
      response_body = json.dumps({'predictions': 'Prediction ran succsessfully'})
    except Exception as e:
      response_body = json.dumps({'error:':str(e)})
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    self.set_header("Content-Length", len(response_body))
    self.write(response_body)
    self.finish()

def make_app():
  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([('/health_check', HealthCheckHandler),
                 ('/predict', PredictionHandler)],
               debug=False)
  tornado_app.listen(8080)
  print("Running App...")
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

and the code of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir -p /app/model
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY app /app/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [expects](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-predictions#response-examples) a specific return-format being `{"predictions":[...]}` and if you do not follow that format, nothing is returned (I'm almost sure).

I do not know tornado, but from your code you might need to change `response_body = json.dumps({'predictions': 'Prediction ran succsessfully'})` to `response_body = json.dumps({'predictions': ['Prediction ran succsessfully']})` and see if that works.